# How to parse this path-like string from SMO?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering, is there any standard way to parse such path-like string:

```
Server[@Name='MyServerName']/Database[@Name='MyDatabaseName']/Table[@Name='MyTableName' and @Schema='MySchemaName']
```

The result must be:

- ItemName (Server)

  - PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue (MyServerName)
- ItemName (Database)

  - PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue (MyDatabaseName)
- ItemName (Table)

  - PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue (MyTableName)
  - PropertyName (Schema), PropertyValue (MySchemaName)

Most obvious here is to make a regular expression (and, of course, `String.Split`), but may be there's a better, standard way?

For the information: the string comes from SMO's [`Urn.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc.urn.value.aspx).

**UPDATE.**

The answer is found, see below.

Comment: A standard way to parse a custom string? :)

Comment: That looks like an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). You might want to look into the [respective classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx) of the .NET framework. Other than that you would have to provide your custom code to do it, or look into ANTLR which has an [xpath grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) (never looked at it, YMMV).

Comment: If you have a way to parse this -> `PropertyName (Schema), PropertyValue (MySchemaName)` Then all you need to do is aggregate/combine it for the rest of your structure.

Comment: @Default: I'm understanding your sarcasm, but may be this string has any type of well-known syntax, which I don't know? I don't like to invent yet another wheel.

Comment: @Christian.K: yes, I'm thinking about XPath too... But I can't understand, how to apply XPath here.

Comment: The result is `Dictionary<>` or XML?

Comment: Are you looking for a standard data structure or only parsing, because you could store this as a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. Except ofc if you want to store the `and` somewhere.

Comment: @Serge: the both will suit me, but XML will be preferred result.

Comment: @Dennis You cannot do much with the XPath classes (of the .NET framework) per se. You need a "stand alone" XPath parser (see my first comment for a link). Note that could be more work than simply writing hand-crafted/specific code. In the end, even with a stock XPath parser, you'd still need to interpret the results so that they make sense to you (the parser obviously doesn't know about "Database" for example).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514879/parse-xpath-expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I did it. :)

The answer is very simple. There's [Urn.XPathExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc.urn.xpathexpression) property. But it's return value type is [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.XPathExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc.xpathexpression), not a [System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.aspx) (this confused me).

And `XPathExpression` from SMO has all necessary features to parse itself:

```
        var urn = new Urn("Server[@Name='MyServerName']/Database[@Name='MyDatabaseName']/Table[@Name='MyTableName' and @Schema='MySchemaName']");

        for (var i = 0; i < urn.XPathExpression.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemName ({0})", urn.XPathExpression[i].Name);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry item in urn.XPathExpression[i].FixedProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tPropertyName ({0}), PropertyValue ({1})", item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
```

produces this output:

```
ItemName (Server)
        PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue ('MyServerName')
ItemName (Database)
        PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue ('MyDatabaseName')
ItemName (Table)
        PropertyName (Name), PropertyValue ('MyTableName')
        PropertyName (Schema), PropertyValue ('MySchemaName')
```

Christian.K, thanks for the hint about XPath!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but i was looking for the same answer, then stumbled apon this on my own.
Urn has a couple of Get functions.

```
 var urn = new Urn("Server[@Name='MyServerName']/Database[@Name='MyDatabaseName']/Table[@Name='MyTableName' and @Schema='MySchemaName']");
    Console.WriteLine(urn.GetNameForType("Table"));
```

Would result in "MyTableName"

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a code app to test, but something like

`var resultArr=str.Split(new char[]{'/', '[',']','@', '='});` should create an array of artifacts you want.

The only thing that remains is to identify correct *array index* for each of them.

Comment: Tigran, thanks for the answer. I have to be more clear in my question: I want to avoid regex'es and `String.Split`.

Comment: @Denis: if there is nothing yet done (it's not a standart string) you need to write a small *parser*. But it sound like cumbersome solution for such task, so if you dont't have **really** serious reasons to not using `Split(..)` or any other built-in function, would suggest to use them.

Comment: @alexn: If you will need to parse 'http://host.domain.com/service?param1=value&param=2' value, will you use `UriBuilder` class? Or you will parse it with `String.Split`? This string **looks like** path, or xpath expression... Of course, if it is not standard, I will use regex'es.

Comment: @Dennis I would use `Uri.Parse`. `String.Split` / `Regex` is a easy and lightweight solution to this problem. Using ANTLR and a XPath grammar is overkill if you only need to parse that simple string. Example: https://gist.github.com/3413106.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the only standard way would be using regular expression **with pattern matching**.

Following code snippet will help -

```
    string input = @"Server[@Name='MyServerName']/Database[@Name='MyDatabaseName']/Table[@Name='MyTableName' and @Schema='MySchemaName']";
    string elementPattern = @"(?<ItemName>\w+)\[@(?<PropertyName>\w+)='(?<PropertyValue>\w+)'( and @(?<PropertyName>\w+)='(?<PropertyValue>\w+)')*\]";

    Regex elementRegex = new Regex(elementPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);

    string[] elements = input.Split('/');

    foreach (string element in elements)
    {
        Match m = elementRegex.Match(element);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemName ({0})", m.Groups["ItemName"]);

            foreach (Capture capture in m.Groups["PropertyName"].Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PropertyName ({0})", capture.Value);
            }

            foreach (Capture capture in m.Groups["PropertyValue"].Captures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PropertyValue ({0})", capture.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Output: -

```
ItemName (Server)
PropertyName (Name)
PropertyValue (MyServerName)
ItemName (Database)
PropertyName (Name)
PropertyValue (MyDatabaseName)
ItemName (Table)
PropertyName (Name)
PropertyName (Schema)
PropertyValue (MyTableName)
PropertyValue (MySchemaName)
```

**Note:** Please make changes as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but "Most obvious here is to make a regular expression" - citation from my question.